ploting zigzag line in different timeframes v5
enter image description here
made a code for plotting zigzag line, I cannot fix it in way that different tfs will plot it  in the same place. I am thinking about to save coordinates of dots and recalculate them for different timeframes, would it be possible?

With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question.
Could you please share your code?
